# Display Multiple Views for Single Page Code Igniter MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, variables

**I have a controller called landingpage.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LandingPage extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
/*header*/  $head = $this->load->view('header_meta', '', true);
            $this->load->view('index', array('head' => $head));

/*guts*/    $guts = $this->load->view('Landing_Guts', '', true);
            $this->load->view('index', array('guts' => $guts));

/*footer*/  $foot = $this->load->view('footerLanding', '', true);
            $this->load->view('index', array('foot' => $foot));
    }
}
```

**footerLanding:**

```
<div id="redStripe_a"> </div>
</div><!--/container_a-->
<div id="footer_a">
            <ul id="footer">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                <span class="red" style="float:right;font-size:0.8em;">&copy; 2012 Co,Inc.</div></span>
                </ul><!--/footer :: ul-->


<div id="clearB"> </div>
    </div><!--/footer_a-->
```

**index.php** (view)

```
<?php echo $head; ?>

<body>
<?php echo $guts; ?>
</body>

<?php echo $foot; ?>
```

I'm getting the following errorss on the page when I load it... but the code has been put into the view because if I `View Source` I see it included in the view's source code.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may want to do some reading on how to properly load views.

```
public function index(){
    // Load each view ONCE
    $data = array(
        'head' => $this->load->view('header_meta', '', true),
        'guts' => $this->load->view('Landing_Guts', '', true),
        'foot' => $this->load->view('footerLanding', '', true)
    );

    // Load index view ONCE, passing variables in data array
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

Code is untested but that's the general idea.  Also, I'd suggest sticking with a single naming convention for your view files.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to pass your sub-views as strings to the `index` view all at once:

```
public function index()
{
  $data = array(
    'head' => $this->load->view('header_meta', '', true),
    'guts' => $this->load->view('Landing_Guts', '', true),
    'foot' => $this->load->view('footerLanding', '', true)
  );

  $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

Right now, you're effectively passing your header, rendering the view, passing the guts, rendering the view, passing the foot, rendering the view, and...well...you get the idea. The error you're seeing results from the first time you try to load `index`--because `$guts` and `$foot` weren't loaded, they weren't available when `$index` tried to `echo` them.